# Как правильно распарсить Json с помощью Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть база данных автомобилей

```
{
     "id": "cars",
     "name": "Легковой",
     "group": "cars",
     "list": {
      "AC": [
       "378 GT Zagato",
       "Ace",
       "Aceca",
       "Cobra"
      ],
      "Acura": [
       "CL",
       "CSX",
       "EL",
       "ILX",
       "Integra",
       "Legend",
       "MDX",
       "NSX",
       "RDX",
       "RL",
       "RLX",
       "RSX",
       "SLX",
       "TL",
       "TLX",
       "TSX",
       "ZDX"
      ],
      "Adler": [
       "Diplomat",
       "Trumpf Junior"
      ],
      "Aion": [
       "S",
       "S Plus"
      ] } }
```

Класс Car

```
public class Car {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String group;

    private List list;
    private List brand;


    public Car(String id, String name, String group, List list, List brand) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.group = group;
        this.list = list;
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public Car() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(List brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
}
```

Не могу понять структуру Jsonа. Почему у поля "list" идут фигурные скобки, а потом массивы значений. Как это описать в Java классе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените в вашем классе

```
private List list;
```

на

```
private Map<String, List<String>> list;
```

где ключом у вас будет марка автомобиля, а значением - список моделей.

Comment: Спасибо большое, благодарен!